# How to read white spaces with scanf

Tags: c, whitespace, scanf, space, backspace

Even though I use this condition in `scanf("[^\n]s", x)`, or `"%34[^\n]"`, or `%127s`, I'm unable to get answers correctly.  Is there any problem with the `scanf` area or in some other part....

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "hello ";
    int a;
    double b;
    unsigned char string_2[100];
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%lf",&b);
    scanf("%[^\n]s",string_2);
    printf("%d",a+i);
    printf("\n%lf",d+b);
    printf("\n%s",s);
    printf("%s",string_2);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%lf",&b);
    scanf("%[^\n]s",string_2);` --> `scanf("%lf",&b);while(getchar()!='\n');
    scanf("%99[^\n]",string_2);`

Comment: yeah that did worked man... awsome .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `scanf` like that.

In this:

```
scanf("%lf",&b);
scanf("%[^\n]s",string_2);
```

The first `scanf` reads a number from the input, but has to wait for your terminal to give the program a complete line of input first. Assume the user `123`, so the program reads `123\n` from the OS.

`scanf` sees the newline that is not part of the number any more, and stops at that *leaving the newline* in the input buffer (within stdio). The second `scanf` tries to read something that is not newlines, but can't do that, since the first thing it sees is a newline. If you check the return value of the `scanf` calls, you'll see that the second scanf returns a zero, i.e. it couldn't complete the conversion you asked for.

Instead, read full lines at a time, with `fgets` or `getline`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    double f;
    getline(&buf, &n, stdin);
    if (sscanf(buf, "%lf", &f) == 1) {
        printf("you gave the number %lf\n", f);
    }
    getline(&buf, &n, stdin);
    printf("you entered the string: %s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

For a longer discussion, see: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html